# Ubuntu 14.04, persistent noise and doesn't shutdown

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, noise

I have a dual boot laptop ASUS ZenBook Pro UX501VW (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04).
After comming back from vacation a lot of updates were done for Ubuntu, including HWE. After restarting, 
my laptop had  a persistent noise (similar to  that one hears  when you tune your radio, but you get a wrong frequency).
Since I did not know the cause of that noise or whether it is harmful or not I tried to shut the system down, but it stayed hanged and did not
shutdown until I pressed the power button. That led to a new boot and the noise was still present.
Can someone, please, suggest how to remove the noise and make the system shutdown?

EDIT:  Meanwhile I deduced that the noise is produced by fan because the CPU frequency in high. Here is what `lscpu` displays:

```
lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 94
Stepping:              3
CPU MHz:               800.007
BogoMIPS:              5183.87
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              6144K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

and here `cpuinfo`:

```
proc/cpuinfo | grep Mhz 
cpu MHz     : 3470.898
cpu MHz     : 3409.148
cpu MHz     : 3314.593
cpu MHz     : 3486.843
cpu MHz     : 3380.406
cpu MHz     : 3385.687
cpu MHz     : 3300.273
cpu MHz     : 3301.492
```

I suspect that this behaviour is caused by LTSEnhancement.

Comment: Does the noise continue when you mute your speakers?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, the noise continue even after mutting the speakers. I've also installed tlp and set save power on 0, and no improvement.

Comment: Update: After `sudo apt-get autoclean` the system shuts down. Only the noise cannot be removed.

Comment: If the noise is in windows too it's a hardware problem otherwise the software updates could be the cause but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  The noise is not present in Windows.

Comment: Your problem sounds similar to this link: [PulseAudio static](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211318) which has been solved there.